# Split string on value unknown amount of times

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to have a field that is populated by the user split on the character ",".  However there could be a varying number of commas in the users text. I am using this for JDBC, where the user enters an entire query and I can save the columns they selected in an array.

For example, I would want to do a simple split like below.

```
String usr = "SELECT NAME, DATE, AGE, PETS FROM CUSTOMER";
String[] parts = usr.split(",");
String[] part1 = parts[0];
String[] part2 = parts[1];
String[] part3 = parts[2];
```

Only instead of presetting the amount of arrays, generate the minimum amount of part arrays to hold the string, without creating a lot of potentially empty arrays.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: The value of a member of an array of a String[] -- an array of Strings -- is a String. No member is itself is a String[]. You can find the length of the array with `parts.length`. You can iterate over the members with a `for` or `while` loop.

Comment: `where the user enters an entire query and I can save the columns they selected in an array` - You are aware that this way you'll get `SELECT NAME` as first column and `PETS FROM CUSTOMER` as last column, are you?

Comment: Any regex based solution might lead to bugs in the long run even if you could extract columns now. IMO it is best to write your own SQL parser. one example of a third party parser [here](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser)

Comment: @BackSlash I just threw together quickly to give a sense, my apologies I did not focus more on the implementation.  However my question was more the best way to go about doing something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution below:

```
private List<String> getColumnNames( String query, Connection conn )
{
    List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
    try
    {
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSetMetaData meta = ps.getMetaData();
        if ( meta != null )
        {
            for ( int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); i++ ) //columns start with "1" not "0" for ResultSetMetaData.
            {
                columnNames.add( meta.getColumnName(i) );
            }
        }
    }
    catch ( SQLException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return columnNames;
}
```

What this code does is - It gets metadata about `ResultSet` that **will** be returned when the statement is executed. But you **won't** execute it. It is just to check the sanity of query and also get the columns in the query!

The `PreparedStatement` is precompiled and hence contains `metadata` about the `ResultSet` that will be returned when the query is executed , but as I said you don't need to execute - only purpose here is to sanity check and get the column names.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting `"SELECT NAME, DATE, AGE, PETS FROM CUSTOMER"` on `","` whill result in

```
["SELECT NAME", " DATE", " AGE", " PETS FROM CUSTOMER"]
```

You don't need to split every element after the first split.